# How do I calculate Power Attack penalties?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, feats

With the feat Power Attack in 3.5, it lets you subtract from your base attack bonus to do more damage. If I have more than one base attack bonus, say +10/+5, and plan to use power attack twice, would it be -10 on both rolls or -10/-5 ?

Comment: Hi!  We do one question per question here.  I've deleted your second question instead of just closing this one as "too broad," you can ask it separately.

Answer (score 4):

## Power Attack uses "your BAB", not "the attack's BAB"

Power Attack:

> On your action, before making attack rolls for a round, you may choose to subtract a number from all melee attack rolls and add the same number to all melee damage rolls. This number may not exceed **your base attack bonus**. The penalty on attacks and bonus on damage apply until your next turn.

Thus, if he power-attacked for 10, he'd take a -10 on all attacks, including off-turn attacks, until his next turn, and get the appropriate bonus to damage.

## 140 Damage by level 10 is easy

To start, let's assume a Barbarian 10 with Power-Attack and Elite Array.

At level 10, his Str is ~23, easily.  That means he's dealing 2d6+30 on each attack when power-attacking for full using a +1 greatsword and a +4 Strength item.  That's 74 damage already, and we've barely started.

Leap Attack, a common addition, under a conservative reading of the Errata, would add another +40 damage, bringing us up to 114 damage.

Enlarge Person, a common buff for level 10s, would add 1d6 damage to the greatsword and +2 Str.  Combine with Half-Orc to avoid rounding on Str, and that's another 1d6+3 damage per swing, or 127 damage total.

At this point, we only need 6.5 damage per attack to break your figure, and I've only picked 2 items, 2 feats, a race and a buff, all available by level 6.  Vicious or Flaming+Frost would get us the rest of the way.  Valorous(3.0 weapon ability) or Whirling Frenzy ACF would be overkill.  A party bard with optimized Inspire Courage could have a +7 to give to the Barbarian's damage rolls.  Tons of ways of doing this.

Answer (score 2):

You only have one base attack bonus, that would be the first number, the +10. The second number +5 would be the iterative attack which having a BAB higher than +5 grants during a full attack.

Power attack allows you to subtract up to your BAB (only BAB, not attack bonuses from other sources such as having a high strength or enhanced weapons) and convert that into extra damage, provided you hit. This subtraction does affect all melee attack rolls until the start of your next round (means AOO's are affected).

Since PA affects BAB, it would be -10 on all rolls if you decided to convert all your BAB into damage, so your original +10/+5 would become 0/-5, while gaining the +10 on damage with regular weapons or +20 with two handed.